# Bubbles in bubble chart are not aligned on exact year-month values (x-axis)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bubble chart which has a simple 3 column data source. For x-axis I use YYYY-MM format and I want to show the total COUNT of something. I was expecting all of the bubbles align vertically on the x-axis year-month dates, but it is not what I get. I am wondering why? and whether there is a reason for such a distribution (how ggplot2 chooses those x values instead of the x value right on the year-month dates)?

**Code:**

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=YMDate, y=`Total Material Count`)) + 
  scale_y_log10() +
  scale_size_continuous(trans="sqrt",
                        range = c(2, 20),
                        breaks=c(1,5,10,50,100,500,1000,2000,3000)) +
  labs(subtitle="Size of Bubble= Total Material Count in MMRs",
       title="MMR Distribution - Monthly")

g <- g + geom_jitter(aes(col=Business, size=`Total Material Count`), alpha=0.7) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(col=Business), method="lm", se=F)
```

**Sample of data:**

[image]

**Bubble Chart(click to enlarge):**

[image]

Comment: It's because you're using `geom_jitter`, which is the preferred way to plot multiple points with the same x-value, to minimize overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nielfws pointed out, you are using `geom_jitter` which is actually a shortcut for `geom_point(position = "jitter")`. If you care more about alignment to the x-axis you can use `position` variable to specify a vertical dodge.

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=YMDate, y=`Total Material Count`)) + 
  scale_y_log10() +
  scale_size_continuous(trans="sqrt",
                        range = c(2, 20),
                        breaks=c(1,5,10,50,100,500,1000,2000,3000)) +
  labs(subtitle="Size of Bubble= Total Material Count in MMRs",
       title="MMR Distribution - Monthly")

g <- g + geom_point(aes(col=Business, size=`Total Material Count`), alpha=0.7,
position = position_dodge(height = 1)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(col=Business), method="lm", se=F)
```

You can also specify a `width` option inside `position_dodge`. Play around to get the desired effect.